# How to change Gnome-Terminal title?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, titlebar

I have several instances of terminals running in my working environment, what I would like is to set a specific title for each one, in order to have a clear idea what purpose the specific terminal serves i.e. Apache, editing_ini, postgres etc...

Of course from the command line.

Comment: Further to Ward's comment: Don't forget to "unset PROMPT_COMMAND" *before* you send the title-change escape sequence, otherwise any change you make will be lost as soon as the next shell prompt.

Comment: For a similar question for KDE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782159/renaming-konsole-from-commandline-after-ssh

Comment: I had this issue when switching from OS X to Ubuntu. To obtain custom titles within a multi-tab set-up, I used `gnome-terminal --load-config` together with [this script](https://github.com/halfer/terminal-tweak) I've written.

Comment: add following to your .bashrc file in your home dir `# set title of current terminal
setTerminalTitle(){
 echo -ne "\033]0;${1}\007"
}

alias termttl=setTerminalTitle` now you can use termttl alias for setting title e.g. `termttl askubuntu`

Comment: "Protected" so I can't supply an answer. Gnome3 `gnome-terminal` default is `PROMPT_COMMAND=__vte_prompt_command`. This uses values from Profiles in prefs. When multiple profiles exist, _New Tab_ and _New Window_ menu items have a submenu item for each Profile. The manual way is to open a new terminal tab, right click on the tab title, and select _Set Title..._. (This would read so much easier in a separate answer, but ...)

Comment: How to set gnome-terminal title? See here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563) and here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/566383#566383).

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Alternatives:

- There are other ways however, you can also issue

  ```
  gnome-terminal --title="SOME TITLE HERE"
  ```

  This might not give the desired effect since there is a big chance that your `.bashrc` overwrites that behaviour.
- Bringing us to the last method, which I shamelessly ripped out of my `.bashrc`.

  ```
  PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'
  ```

As an extra reference, this is the particular line in my `.bashrc`

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
```

You may also need to comment this code out in your `~/.bashrc`

```bash
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    # JEFFYEE REMOVED because it makes commands to title() not work
    #PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Need to comment out or remove as you mentioned in order to take effect!

Comment: @DoR the code PROMPT_COMMAND=... I commented it out. If not removed from the .bashrc then the title remains the same since its getting override by the .bashrc settings.

Comment: @DoR That seems odd given `PS1` is the variable for the actual prompt. Hmm, that makes me wonder why  the one for the title gets called `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Anyone know anything about that?

Comment: @Ward: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a *program* to run.  `PS1` and `PS1` are *textual strings* that are displayed.  In the example above the command that is run is `echo`, which then simply prints out a string.  See `man bash` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash for more details.

Comment: I wonder why this `--title` option is not documented in `gnome-terminal --help`!

Comment: @umpirsky it is in `--help-all`

Comment: note, if you do not see the menu bar in the terminal, you may activate it by right-clicking in the terminal and checking `Show Menubar`

Comment: GNOME Terminal 3.16.2 says `Option "--title" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.`

Comment: I had to escape the `~` in `${PWD/$HOME/~}` to get the home directory replaced: `${PWD/$HOME/\~}`.

Comment: On Gnome 3.18.3, there is no "Set title" entry in the menus :/

Comment: For anyone else confused by the gobbledegook in the strings above, they are ANSI escape characters - see e.g. http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/774543/455406 sets the title programmatically; it is bash-specific.

Comment: GNOME terminal 3.20 does not have "set title..." in the menu

Comment: @WardMuylaert Any way to have it open a new tab instead of anew window?

Comment: @WillC Thanks for that link, it's the only programmatic answer on this page that worked!

Comment: In PROMPT_COMMAND I need to escape `~` : `${PWD/$HOME/\~}`   Gnome Terminal 3.28.

Answer (score 98):

Ward's answer is great if you want to set your title based on what host you're on etc every time you open a terminal. If you just want to quickly set a title though, you can just run echo by itself:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"
```

or make a simple function (inside your `~/.bashrc`), say `termtitle`

```
termtitle() { printf "\033]0;$*\007"; }
```

which you can run with `termtitle some title here`.

Comment: or similarly we can add as bash alias by adding below lines in ~/.bash_aliases
`function set_title() {
     echo -ne "\033]0;${1}\007" 
}   
alias title=set_title`
and then use:   `$ title term_title`

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to work for me in GNOME terminal 3.6.2.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work in xterm 322 or konsole 16.12... I don't know if there's a new method, unfortunately :(

Comment: Why do you have to use `${1}` instead of `$1`?

Comment: @3ocene it doesn't actually matter in this case, they are the same thing, but it's a good habit to get into, because e.g. `$var_log` and `${var}_log` are very different things, and the difference can cause bugs in scripts.

Comment: I guess this only works if your bash prompt does not overwrite it again. Other terminals (such as MATE terminal, or KDE konsole) support overwriting the term title on the GUI level even if the shell sets a title. I guess the real answer to this question should be GNOME terminal simply does not support it

Comment: if it doesn't work for you it is probably because PROMPT_COMMAND var or PS1 var is set and is over-riding it. ```unset PROMPT_COMMAND``` or set it so that it also changes the title e.g.  ```export PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "$(basename $PWD)"'```

Answer (score 39):

Argh, so many answers...

I tried `wmctrl`, which *almost* worked, except I couldn't get it to change the icon title, at least not permanently.

The problem is that the PS1 in Bash in Ubuntu sets the title.

The default PS1 is

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

... which sets the title in the first escape sequence: `\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a`

Thus, there are two solutions:

### Solution 1: simplify PS1, then use PROMPT_COMMAND

Change PS1 to something simpler:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

Then use the PROMPT_COMMAND:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'
```

### Solution 2: directly modify PS1

Simply modify PS1 with new title:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;newtitle\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

### Notes on escape codes

Note that (borrowing from wjandrea's comment below this answer):

- `\e` or `\033` is the escape (ESC) character, which starts an escape sequence.
- `]` starts an operating system command (OSC).
- For an xterm, `0;` means "set the title", and
- `\a` or `\007` is the bell (BEL) character that terminates the OSC.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences

Comment: hi, I like your answer quite a lot. Would you mind explaining the role of `]0;` in your code? I think I found the meaning of `echo -e '\007 \033'` with the `ascii -o` command…although I’m truthfully not sure what that’s doing there either … thanks …

Comment: @iso `\e` or `\033` is the escape (ESC) character, which starts an escape sequence. `]` starts an operating system command (OSC). For an xterm, `0;` means "set the title", and `\a` or `\007` is the bell (BEL) character that terminates the OSC. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences

Comment: @wjandrea I was looking for the equivalent escape letters (`\e` and `\a`) for `\033` and `\007` but I couldn't find them certainly because I didn't know the right keywords to type in google. The link you gave is also useful. Can you please convert your comment to an answer ?

Comment: This should be the Accepted answer! It took me an hour of research to figure it out, why the accepted and the second answer did not work for me. (And it's my bad, because I red only the first two answers).

Comment: A great, if not the best answer. Small correction: `0;` means "set title _and icon name_". For the title only use `2;`

Comment: @Aba Before saying this should be the accepted answer, take your own advise of not only reading the first two to find this fourth answer, and read the sixth one :). FTR #6 was written by yours truly.

Comment: Technically speaking, OSC sequences should end with `ST` (String Terminator, i.e. ``\e\``); the bell character was supported only for compatibility. However, overtime the bell character got more popular somehow. Modern terminals (terminal emulators) support both. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences).

Answer (score 37):

If you use the Vim editor, you can also enable this option in your vimrc:

```
:set title
```

which is disabled by default. It will set cool terminal titles showing the filename which you are editing at the moment and some other things.

Comment: this give name that will change every time not usefull
:set notitle

Answer (score 30):

For the sake of completeness, I would add that you can also set the `gnome-terminal` title using this command:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "MyWindowTitle"
```

You'll need to install the package [wmctrl [image: Install wmctrl]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) first.

Comment: MyWindowTitle does not show up in title of terminal. It shows up when I do wmctrl -m.

Comment: Note that wmctrl changes window title and not the tab title, whereas the escaped characters solution changes the tab title. Moreover, window title change back to original tab title as soon as you switch between tabs.

Comment: This didn't work for me with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 30):

## Works on Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.10

This answer is simpler than most others. To use it, you would just type:

### `title "My new title"`

- Easier to remember than most other answers.
- The accepted answer and others do not work on modern versions of Ubuntu (from **16.04** on up).
- This answer doesn't require 3rd party packages like `wmctrl` and `xdotool`.
- Version 2 allows running multiple times in the same session.

---

### One-time function creation

Create the `title` function in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
function title() {
    # Set terminal tab title. Usage: title "new tab name"
    prefix=${PS1%%\\a*}                  # Everything before: \a
    search=${prefix##*;}                 # Eeverything after: ;
    esearch="${search//\\/\\\\}"         # Change \ to \\ in old title
    PS1="${PS1/$esearch/$@}"             # Search and replace old with new
}
```

Save the `~/.bashrc` file. After opening a new terminal tab use:

```bash
title "Special Projects"
```

or:

```bash
title Special\ Projects
```

A phrase with spaces must be wrapped in double quotes (`"`) or each space must be escaped with `\`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that worked for me with GNOME terminal 3.36.2.

Comment: Thank you, it works with Gnome Terminal 3.36.2 but only once. I mean after you set the title, you can't change it anymore.

Comment: @MinhNguyen I've upgraded function to allow renaming multiple times per session. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix. It works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is the specific implementation I'm using successfully in gnome-terminal 3.36.2, on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Thanks! This worked on GNOME terminal 3.38.1.  Renaming worked also! (Upvoted.)

Comment: Awesome! This worked on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This is black magic at its finest (though, if you have it, .bash_aliases is probably a better place for it) Thank you

Comment: Worked for Gnome 3.46.2 and Ubuntu 22.10!

Comment: @newalvaro9 Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the answer to show Version **22.10** works too.

Answer (score 9):

If you are a Ubuntu user, you can change the title of a gnome-terminal tab using the [HUD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD).

While in the gnome-terminal, hit Alt to bring up the HUD, type the first few letters, e.g. "tit", hit enter and type in your new title.

This is a very quick method and avoids using the mouse.

(UPDATE: In newer versions of gnome-terminal, this was removed. Try other answers.)

Comment: Indeed. Keeps the hands on the keyboard. The existing title is displayed, so it's fast and easy to also just modify the existing one using this method.

Comment: _tit_ is only for English Ubuntu.

Comment: and the whole option has been removed :(

Comment: the `F2` key also avoids the mouse.

Comment: @törzsmókus And French - *titre* ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another way of changing the title of `gnome-terminal` is by using `gconftool-2`; this changes the initial terminal title for the *profile* selected, so you could have different profiles associated with titles such as 'Apache', 'Editing', etc. You would then launch `gnome-terminal` with the appropriate profile to get the terminal title you had specified. This is in contrast to `gnome-terminal --title "name"` which changes the title per terminal, but doesn't affect the initial title specified in the profile.

You could use the following command in a script to set the name of the terminal for a profile, and you could have the name of the terminal change at certain times in the day to remind you of things:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/title --type=string "Apache"
```

This is for the default profile, but you could set the title for other profiles as well by changing, for example, `Default` to another profile like `Profile0`:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile0/title --type=string "Editing"
```

I thought this way of changing the title is of use because of the way it could be used in scripting, or just as a quick command-line way to set the title for the profile. Note that sometimes you have to relaunch the terminal with the specified profile for the `gconftool-2` setting to take affect. The complete settings available for `gnome-terminal` can be listed with `gconftool-2 -R /apps/gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 3):

To display only the current working directory in the title, try this in your '.bashrc' :

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0; ${PWD##*/}\007"'
```

or

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename ${PWD})\007"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use xdotool to simulate keystrokes, maybe useful in scripts:

1. Set a keyboard shortcut in gnome-terminal:

   ```
   Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts... > Terminal > Set Title
   ```

   For example assing the `Shift+Ctrl+Y`.
2. Install `xdotool` if you don't have it already:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
3. The following sequence of commands (that you can use also in a bash script) will set the terminal/tab title (escape the spaces with `\`):

   ```
   xdotool key ctrl+shift+y 
   xdotool type My\ new\ fabulous\ title
   xdotool key Return
   ```
4. [optional] You can also use xdotool to e.g. open a new tab and set the title with the above commands, using:

   ```
   xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
   ```

   Consider adding a sleep time before and after opening a new tab, e.g. `sleep 1` (to wait for 1 second).

This is not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me! The previous answers did not work in my case. I use gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 and I wanted to make a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

This worked in my **Gnome Terminal 3.18.3**.

Edit your *.bashrc* file and add this function

```
# Update gnome terminal title
function termtitle() {
    # take argument
    TITLE=$1
    shift
    # update title
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0; $TITLE \007"'
}
```

Don't forget to `source` your *.bashrc* file

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

And then you can simply update you'll be able to change terminal title like this:

```
$ termtitle "MariaDB CLI"
```

Comment: On stock Ubuntu 20.04 with preinstalled `gnome-terminal 3.36.2 using VTE 0.60.3` this does not do anything. [This other similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164880/1157519) however works.

Comment: worked on my Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

easy Ubuntu 20.04 way (*from https://askubuntu.com/a/1366329/149527)

> PS1=$PS1"[\e]0;New_Terminal_Name\a]"

Comment: This did the trick for me: `PS1=$PS1"\e]0;New_Terminal_Name\a"`

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, however it causes problems with my prompt as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453576/terminal-prompt-messed-up-after-changing-value-of-ps1). Overall a good quick and dirty solution

Answer (score 1):

In case any poor souls like myself are forced to use tcsh, try something like this in your .cshrc:

```
set prompt='%{\033]0;%n@%m\007%}%~%# '
```

Source and more details: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html

Comment: The question was asking how to set the title to a custom value, not have it automatically generated from the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gnome 3, the convenient `Terminal > Set Title` menu option has been removed.  You can install a gnome 2 forked terminal which still has that "Set Title" menu option, and run that instead:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-terminal
```

Instead of running "Terminal", run "MATE Terminal".  You should probably also select mate-terminal in `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to other valid answers, `xdotool` has the functionality that allows you to change the title of any application and window.

```
xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name "WINDOW NAME HERE"
```

Note that the change won't be permanent, it'll change when you change directory and probably be set to your PWD.

To permanently change it, you can modify `PS1` variable within `~/.bashrc` as mentioned.

```
PS1="${PS1}\[\e]0;New Title\a\]"
```

This modification is permanent. In fact after this, the changes you make with `xdotool` will also be permanent and won't change with `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

for a wsl (windows subsystem for linux) terminal tab i'll do this:

```
# function to set terminal title
function set-title(){
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG="$PS1"
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1="${ORIG}${TITLE}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.vimrc file along with the

```
set title
```

command

add the line

```
set titleold=
```

The old window title will reappear when you exit vim. It was already thought of!

Also, people who have been using vi since the 80's may find
that using an arrow key does not bump you into command mode.
Add this to ~/.vimrc if you want 80's terminal behavior

```
" vi users may expect that if you are 
" in INSERT mode if an arrow key is pressed it will hop back 
" into command mode. 
"
inoremap <left> <esc><left>
inoremap <right> <esc><right>
inoremap <up> <esc><up>
inoremap <down> <esc><down>
```

Comment: The question is not about vim, it's about terminals in general. For example, one might want to set the title without launching vim (or any other application) at all.