# Identify the server I'm working at

Tags: command-line, ssh

How to identify which server you're on when using ssh from terminal?

I have to ssh into 30 servers daily, and switch between them constantly.
Currently I'm editing the tab name and writing the IP iddress to jump from one to another.

Is there an automated way of doing this (assigning the server IP address as the tab name)?  Any other alternatives that won't involve editing a file on each server?

Comment: what do you need to know toidentify your server? I simply type in "hostname" to see the servers name. That's enough for me to know because we used to use a good naming convention

Comment: currently i have `user@hostname` on the first host i connect. i would like to see the ip address. also, if i jump from `server1` to `server2`, the tab doesn't change names.

Comment: yes that's your name, but I mean servername. there must a hostname for that machine. isn't that enough info for you?

Comment: i also meant `user@servername`. thats the tab title. but it would be better if i could have the server's ip address as tab title (automagically).

Comment: This sounds like something you can do by switching your ssh client.

Comment: How about setting the background color of your terminals? Depending on how you connect and what terminal you're using you could be able to automate it. For example, I may set a dark red background for production servers so I know I have to be extra careful, especially when connecting simultaneously to staging servers which look and feel exactly the same.

Comment: If you are switching between 30 servers constantly then you need to look at scripting and tools like puppet for management. Also if an IP is more recognisable than the hostname, these don't sound like good hostnames!

Answer (score 11):

I usually use the hostname, set via `$PS1`. However, if you'd take the trouble, you can start using GNU `screen` and then you could define a function like so:

```bsh
function ssh-title () {
    host="${@: -1}"  # You could customize it to make it identify the hostname better
    IP=$(host "$host" | awk '/has address/ { print $4 }')
    echo -ne '\033]0;'"$host"' - '"$IP"'\007'
    screen ssh "$@"
}
```

Explanation:

1. Even if you set a title from your local shell, it may get overwritten by the remote shell settings. `screen` doesn't directly let the remote shell do this, and you have to customize it to allow it do so, making it easier for you to set a title locally and stick to it.
2. Look up [IP from hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20793/70524), while considering the [last parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854031/2072269) as the hostname, and set it as the title. I had to do a bit of [trial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157751/2072269) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687708/2072269) [error](https://superuser.com/a/399860/334516) before I got a right `echo` string. You might have to do it too.
3. Finally, use `screen` to start a session with the `ssh` command. The session ends when the command exits.

You can customize this in various ways. For example, you may save the hostnames and IPs in a file and read from it (kinda like the `ssh_config`) (and maybe save other things for the title, like usernames).

Now use `ssh-title some.host` to connect. I think this is the only way you can do this without editing anything server side.

Answer (score 5):

A few ways to identify a server:

- [SSH fingerprint](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-essentials-checking-a-server%E2%80%99s-ssh-host-fingerprint-with-the-web-console) - secure but changes whenever you redeploy.
- Shell prompt (`PS1`) and [terminal title](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/0df549fdf974729d5fe046602c4ae76de2eee586/.bashrc#L113) - insecure (anybody can duplicate it) but simple and practical.
- `ip address` - secure with an SSH fingerprint, and more easily readable.
- `hostname` - insecure but very readable.

Comment: thanks. and how would you automatically add that as your terminal tab title?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt) --- works for both `bash` and `zsh`, and can be easily configured to have the terminal title set and even to color in different colors the hostname in the prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a little hackish, but I think it will do what you're looking for. You will need `xdotool` and `wmctrl` installed for this to work.

First you have to edit your `~/.bashrc` file because by default the terminal resets its title after every line, rendering command line title sets useless.

Right after: `xterm*|rxvt*)`

Replace: `PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"`

With: `PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a$ "`

Next we're going to create a custom `ssh` script called whatever you want, but for this answer I'll be calling mine `tab-ssh`. Open a text editor and save the following as `tab-ssh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID

sleep 1
title=$(echo "$*" | sed s/.*@//g)
xdotool type --delay 1 --clearmodifiers 'echo -en "\033]0;"'"${title}"'"\a"'
xdotool key Return

sleep 1
xdotool type --delay 1 --clearmodifiers "ssh $*"
xdotool key Return
```

Then make it executable:

`chmod +x tab-ssh`

Now, assuming you're using `bash` and `gnome-terminal`, running the script should open a new tab, rename it, and start the `ssh` session. For exmaple:

`tab-ssh username@0.0.0.0`

will open a new tab, rename it to `0.0.0.0` (i.e. everything following the "@" sign), then execute `username@0.0.0.0`.

Created using the following:

- [AskUbuntu: Setting titles in gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/31004/205638)
- [StackOverflow: Opening a new tab in gnome-terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/2258915)
- [StackOverflow: Single quotes and variable expansion in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/2258915)