# How to organize my terminals?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Sometimes I'm using a lot of terminals for server communication, and what boders me is that sometimes I'm lost, so I want to organize my terminal windows by name or tag or something that will make a difference betwen terminal A and terminal B.

Now I have something like this:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the server names always the same then?  Like its 6 connections and 6 terminals all to the same location?

Comment: This might be helpful, there still might be a better way.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title

Comment: Server names (hostname) are different, but if I run for example htop, then I can not see hostname.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527083/identify-the-server-im-working-at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I've tried with this, but it's not anymore supported:

```
gnome-terminal --title="SOME TITLE HERE"

Option "--title" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.
```

So I've solved with this: `echo -ne '\033]0;New title\007'`

Comment: You can also look up how to change the title depending on which directory or application it's currently running.  This would be

Answer (score 1):

You could use `terminator`. It does support names for terminal windows.
You can install terminator by using `sudo apt-get install teminator`

Comment: It would be nice if you add how to install terminator.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer.

Comment: A screenshot could be a nice addition as well. ;)