# Ubuntu 18.10 how to rename current terminal Tab title

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

I want to rename my current terminal tab - window title.
Please help me how to do it either using CUI or GUI.

Comment: This might help or be a duplicate don't know: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title Stolen from this post: `echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"` will set your title and your tab to "SOME TITLE HERE". Might depend on the terminal you use. This worked for me with Gnome Terminal & Terminator.

Comment: I want to change the window title

Comment: Why have you flagged 14.04?   The link provided by Patient32Bit worked on 14.04 LTS, but I didn't have as much luck with my 19.04 (but I didn't try them all)  Why flag 14.04?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1577927)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [long standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1577927) that appears to have been 1st reported around 2016.

A currently viable workaround is to install mate-terminal which still has the ability to set the title of the terminal screen as reported by [Erik B. Andersen](https://launchpad.net/~erik-b-andersen+azendale) in [this bug report comment.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1577927/comments/4)

I have tested this workaround under Ubuntu 16.04 as well as 18.04 and can testify that it does indeed work as advertised.

The downside is that it requires the installation of [other Mate related supporting packages.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mate-terminal)