# Function to change title doesn't work when run in script

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I've got a simple command that sets the term title:

```
# Allow the user to set the title.
function title {
   PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\033]0;$1 ($PWD)\007\""
}
export -f title
```

I'd like to access this from a script:

```
16:28 $ cat ./scripts/webserver.sh
#!/bin/bash
title 'webserver'
nodemon ./app/webserver.coffee
```

I've placed `title` in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.profile` and sourced every one of those files after. I can run the `title` function fine from the command line. Regardless of what I do, the title function doesn't run when I run my script file. There's no error, just no change to the title. What am I doing wrong?

A bit more info: I added an `echo 'changing title'` line in the title function. The echo is being output but the title isn't being changed. So there must be a problem with the title function?

Related: [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the title of the terminal, I'd advise you to use `wmctrl` that will also work from within a script (in fact, your solution fails because the prompt is not used when running scripts). So, first install the `wmctrl` package, e.g., using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

The nice thin with `bash` is that it has a variable named `WINDOWID` that contains a window id (no kidding!) that `wmctrl` can use. From within Bash or from within a script, try:

```
wmctrl -ir $WINDOWID -N "A cool title"
```

- The `-i` option is to tell `wmctrl` that the window will be specified using its numerical id (do `echo $WINDOWID` to check that `WINDOWID` is indeed a number, and do `wmctrl -l` to list all the windows managed by your window manager and compare... you'll probably have to convert from decimal to hexadecimal or maybe use `printf '%#.8x\n' "$WINDOWID"`).
- The `-r` option is to tell `wmctrl` that the specified window will be ready for the following action, i.e., `-N`, change its title to the specified title.

`man wmctrl` for more info about this funny little tool.

Enjoy!