# gnome-terminal is secretive with the runing process in its titlebar (a bug or ?)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, titlebar, wmctrl, system-info

## Misbehavior of the new gnome terminal (18.04)

I used to use [`wmcrtl`](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+wmcrtl+command+linux) to search for the proper window on my crowded desktop and to raise it, set the focus or to do other [wm](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+ubuntu+18.04+window+manager) operations...

However it doesn't behave as usual with the [bionic beaver](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=bionic+beaver) a.k.a [Ubuntu 18.04](https://seeks.hsbp.org/?language=en&engines=google,duckduckgo,qwant,ixquick,startpage&q=Ubuntu+18.04+misbehavior)
the title got indeed updated when one does a [cd](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+cd+updating+the+window+title) (thanks to the [PS1](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+PS1+prompt+variable) variable) however when you run a command in
it is doesn't take the application info to display the title the time of a run !
[Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327283/gnome-terminal-does-not-allow-changing-the-title) partially answered the question, however I believe the terminal used to display the "[process string](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+exec+argument+process+status+info+string)" from the `execlp()` system call when the shell forked the command.

This makes my trick to discover windows a little more difficult.
`xterm` and `rxvt` does continue to display an expected behavior.

Is this a bug introduced in 18.04 or it is intentional ?
Question: how to have the 2nd argument of the `execlp()` issued to execute the current running process, displayed in the title-bar ?
any setting to re-enable the feature or any work-around available ?

-- 
+ygl

Comment: Continuing on the topic of the new [Gnome-Terminal titlebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078221/) :
a trap (like in [this](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/zb2rhkJDPVM4BUYyb9Z1MK54x8s4CiJy5RyXdQmxpDscFWqdj) link), might do the trick for some, still I believe it will mess up with the
shell [completion](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!g+bash+completion+mechanism+ubuntu) mechanism.