# Terminal prompt messed up after changing value of PS1

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I carelessly entered a command in the terminal that should have been in a shell script:

```
export PS1=$PATH:~/drush23/drush/
```

now in my terminal instead of this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-16-134-18:/home/ubuntu$
```

I see this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ubuntu/drush23/drush/
```

and when I change directories this line always stays...
I don't know what to do

I have byobu...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$PS1` is an environment variable that tells yours shell how to format the prompt. Changing the value with `export`, as you did, only applies to that session; so you can just open up a new shell (not a sub-shell) and see a familiar prompt.

Otherwise, if you *really* want your prompt back in this session itself, just rerun your shell's preferences file. For Bash users, that is:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

I don't know if that will work (at least, without causing other issues) for Byobu; but you can just set the prompt to a sane value like this:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Or, if you don't want to or can't have a colour prompt, a simpler one would be:

```
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

where `\u` is your username, `\h` is your hostname, and `\w` is the full (logical) path of your current working directory.

Comment: i wasn't aware the $PS1 controlled that... thanks!

Comment: just hit in terminal `. ~/.bashrc`. It will reset `PS1` variable and you should get back your prompt.

Comment: @souravc Are you sure that wouldn't cause problems for the OP? he's using Byobu.

Comment: @YatharthROCK I don't think it would cause any problem. What are you expecting as possible problem?

Comment: @souravc Sorry, wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: do you have an extra `PS1=` in there ? :)

Comment: Your second option rescued and restored my prompt, thanks!
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

Answer (score 1):

You can set `PS1` to a reasonable value for this Terminal session using:

```
export PS1=$'\h:\w\$'
```

The old value should also be restored after closing and restarting Terminal, a reboot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I used PS1 to set the prompt to "Test"..

Later I was unable to go back to the default colored prompt.

however i was checking some answer in this website & i had to check which shell i'm running.

**I tried $SHELL & it got reset to it's default colored prompt value.**

**"$SHELL"**

I'm not a pro in this. This is purely accidental, I don't know if this will work for you or not.

But it's worth a try.

Comment: Can you explain what you you did to `SHELL`?

Comment: I really have no idea how it worked.. I didn't edit anything related to shell either. Do check out the screenshot link : https://imgur.com/a/l4SGtBK

Comment: FYI, this simply runs a new shell. If you run `exit`, you'll be back to the messed up prompt.