# Root@clear is showing instead of showing host name

Tags: users, user-management, username, user-profile, switch-user

I don't what happened there was crash or some thing my prompt is changed into like user name root@clear usually it shows username like root@local.localdomain
How can I revert back to previous state and remove this clear word next to the user name.
Thanks

Comment: Does that persist after starting another session? Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453576/terminal-prompt-messed-up-after-changing-value-of-ps1

Comment: Please, add the output of commands `hostname`, `dnsdomainname` and `id` into your original question.

Comment: I have just manually changed the file /etc/hostname and I changed host name from clear to local.

Comment: I changed manually hostname file from /etc/hostname clear to local but it is still displaying clear @ console window like shahzad@clear:

Comment: Dnsdomainname is not showing any out put