# how to give each terminal tab its own title?

Tags: command-line, unity, gnome-terminal, gui, tweak

I see that there are ways to [set the tabs title through the CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title), but how can I give each tab its own "title"?

1. top
2. pine
3. git

by default, gnome-terminal seems to show `<user>@<host>:<path>`, which gets cumbersome beyond two tabs, IMHO.

*(creating umpteen profiles is way to awkward to be a solution)*

Notably, Alpine seems to magically (through the CLI?) set the tab title:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, if this works for you (can't test it right now...), but try to do a right-click on the title of the tab. There may be an option to change the title

Comment: no such option for me

Answer (score 2):

As taken from [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/62316/renaming-windows-of-shells-in-ubuntu),

The process is a little complex to explain here since it is different for every shell you use. Rather I'll give you two links:

- [How to Change the Title of an
  xterm](https://superuser.com/questions/62316/renaming-windows-of-shells-in-ubuntu) (Comprehensive instructions
  for many different shells)
- [Show the current Command in your
  Bash window Title](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html). A nice step by
  step procedure on how the author went
  on to do this nice effect. Makes for
  a good learning practice. (But bash
  specific)

There are a few other things to take into consideration. For a one time change common to all terminal sessions, you may want instead to simply alter Bash (if you use bash and under gnome) icon and add `--title=title` under Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

The title can be set using escape sequences as shown in [How to change xterm title](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title.html). ( Specifically for [bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html#ss4.3) ).

In their example, they use case statement that sets `PS1`  with an enclosed escape sequence.

```
case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]bash\\$ "
        ;;
    *)
        PS1="bash\\$ "
        ;;
esac
```

The  basic idea is to echo `echo -e "\033]0; STRING\007"` ( The PS1 prompt needs extra `\[...\]` brackets to enclose the escape sequence ). Thus you could add the following function to your `.bashrc` at the top of the file:

```
function setTitle
{
   echo -e "\033]0;$@\007"
}
```

Now  you can alter title at will

Answer (score 1):

You could install and use `xttitle` (Note the doubled `t` in the name). I use it like this in a file sourced by my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [ $TERM = xterm -o $TERM = xterm-color ] && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [ -z "$*" ] && builtin cd $HOME
    [ -n "$*" ] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

I also do this:

```
xttitle Mutt && mutt
```