# byobu show pwd path in gnome terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, byobu

I normally launch byobu as a custom command in my gnome terminal profile preferences:

[image]

In this way it shows the information like this:

[image]

But I would like to display the current path in the terminal's title bar as gnome terminal would if byobu was not launched:

[image]

Comment: You mean display the path on the terminal's top bar? Your second image doesn't make sense: you are showing a file, not a path to a directory.

Comment: @terdon yes, I mean the path on the terminal's top bar. ~/.byobu is a folder...

Comment: Argh, sorry, I thought it was byobu's configuration file. OK, but in your second image, `byobu` isn't running, I don't see the status bar, so it can't be showing what happens if you launch `byobu` manually.

Comment: lol @terdon the OP _wants_ the path to show in the title bar while byobu is running

Comment: it appears to be difficult to customize the gnome-terminal title bar as is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title

Answer (score 0):

i was looking how to launch gnome-terminal directly into byobu and funny enough your question answered my question.
so I did some research into your question and it appears that [byobu is setting the title of the terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1488658/terminal-emulator-with-dynamic-title-from-byobu-tmux-session-name) and that is actually [not configurable even without byobu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)
i also keep reading about `BYOBU_NO_TITLE=1` fixing it but I cannot figure where it is supposed to be set..... i have tried `/usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc` and /usr/share/byobu/profiles/byoburc` no luck

what *did* work is setting the following `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "#(pwd)"
```