# Unable to change gnome-terminal tab title any standard way

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have 2 laptops, A and B, same OS (ubuntu 18.04). My gnome terminal tab titles on A always show current path in the tab, whereas B show it the one I tell it via the `tt` and `ntt` commands I discuss in [another question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496534/269386). I have tried

```
echo -ne "\033]0;MY TITLE\007"'
```

and

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;MY TITLE\007"'
```

and

```
gnome-terminal --title="MY TITLE HERE"
```

but nothing works, it keeps showing the current folder in tab title. Whereas on laptop B, the same commands work! This is a slightliy different question from [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413), because none of the 3 techniques above work.

I remember fiddling around with this a few weeks ago, I must have put something in place that dynamically updates the title every time there is a new prompt, so when I try the echo -ne, it immediately gets overwritten. The env commands shows that there is no PS1 or PROMPT_COMMAND already in place.

Any ideas how to fix this so that echo -ne works again? Is there like a settings file for gnome terminal, it loads every time it starts?

Comment: `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` are not environment variables, so `env` will not show them. Use `declare -p PS1 PROMPT_COMMAND` instead. (I assume you're using Bash.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title) See [Hugh's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/252233/301745).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @wjandrea you were right on with your first comment, and darn close with your second one. So it may be useful to others to know that other than the 3 techniques mentioned in my question, there may be a PS1 sneakily set in your `.bashrc`. Indeed:

1. An `env|grep PS1` will never show `PS1`; instead use `echo $PS1` or `declare -p PS1` similarly for `PROMPT_COMMAND`.
2. Once I used correct query, I found that `PS1` was set with an esc sequence 0, which sets title on tab.
3. Then I looked in my `.bashrc` and sure enough the bit of code discussed in [Ward's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/22417/738406) was there; the block

   ```
   case "$TERM" in 
     xterm*...
   ```

   prepends the magical arcane esc 0 sequence that sets title, thus preventing any of the other techniques from working!
4. Uncommenting it allowed me to use the `tt` and `ntt` commands I mention in [my older question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496534/269386).