# Ubuntu 16.04 problem setting gnome terminal title

Tags: gnome-terminal, titlebar, menu-bar

I am trying to set a custom title on the terminal similar to this question:
[How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)

However, the "PROMPT_COMMAND" answer isn't working, or it's being overwritten somehow. My .bashrc file is completely empty now (for trying to troubleshoot this problem) except for this line:

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'
```

With this, when I open a terminal the "SOME TITLE HERE" shows up in the menubar for about half second or less, just barely noticeable for an instant. So it's as if it's being overwritten by something after the .bashrc? Otherwise, after it blinks, my terminal menubar only has a "Terminal" dropdown menu.

I also would like to get rid of this "Terminal" dropdown if possible, but suspect it might be part of the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: To add to this, the "SOME TITLE HERE" does show up in the menubar when launching XTerm and UXTerm, so the problem is with the default gnome terminal only.

Comment: Another thing I found: the "SOME TITLE HERE" shows up in the tab title in gnome-terminal, but the tab title is only visible if more than one terminal is open in a single window in tabbed mode. With only one terminal, no title. Apparently, where I want the title to appear is in the header bar?