# How to change terminal title?

Tags: command-line

In windows, I just have to type title mytitle to change the title of the terminal.

```
c:\title mytitle
```

How to do it in ubuntu?

Comment: too complicated. must have a simpler way

Comment: It isn't complicated. In my answer you type `termtitle mytitle` It is only complicated if the title is more than one word then you type `termtitle "This is a long title"`.

Comment: This is the specific implementation I'm using successfully in `gnome-terminal` 3.36.2: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164880/1157519 (Someone here will find it familiar :) )

Comment: @Levente Deja Vu

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
gnome-terminal --title="my_title"
```

For this to work, you probably have to comment this fragment in `~/.bashrc`

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    # Comment this
    #PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

You may also try issuing command

```
echo -ne "\033]0;my_title\007"
```

See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title).

Answer (score 0):

this is simple enough

```bsh
set-title(){
  ORIG=$PS1
  TITLE="\e]2;$@\a"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

reference
https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-16-04-set-terminal-title

Comment: You should add that answer to the duplicate candidate. In any respect you still have to add the function to `~/.bashrc` like all the other answers posted in the duplicate candidate.