# Remove PC name from the top of the terminal emulator window

Tags: 20.04

I am using the terminal emulator that comes with the installation of 20.04. I suppose similar questions about the preceding characters of the prompt are asked elsewhere, but what I want is to not show the PC name on top. How can I do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, instead of `taro@host:~$`, you want it to say `taro:~$`? Or do you want something different? 

Comment: @matigo Just ~ is fine, and to be clear, I am talking about the top of the window, which does not include $

Comment: Will [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164880/1222991) do what you’re looking for? 